# How to set request timeout in MQSimpleConnectionManager?

Tags: java, ibm-mq

In am using MQSimpleConnectionManager for connection pooling and while getting MQQueueManager, thread goes into infinite wait state due to some network isaue.

Can someone help me to set request timeout?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure it is a infinite wait?  By default a `SVRCONN` channel will have a `HBINT` value of `300` seconds.  Applications that use either IBM MQ classes for Java or IBM MQ classes for JMS by default use the `HBINT` of the `SVRCONN` value (You can specify a client side value only if you use a CCDT for the client channel def, but even if you do the highest value is what is negotiated at started, so a `SVRCONN` at default of `300` would be the lowest value you could have).

Comment: If either the queue manager or client do not get a response back from a heart beat message the channel will timeout (Assuming a `SVRCONN` channel operating in v7.0 or later mode).  The `TIMEOUT` value is based on the `HBINT`.  If the `HBINT` is less than 60 seconds the `TIMEOUT` is `2*HBINT`, if the `HBINT` is 60 seconds or greater the `TIMEOUT` is `HBINT+60`.  Given this formula a Java or JMS client connecting to a `SVRCONN` channel with a default `HBINT` of `300` will timeout in `360` seconds (`6` minutes).  So when you state it is a infinite wait, have you waited `6` minutes?

Comment: If this is what you are talking about then I can post a answer explaining it or vote to close it as a duplicate of a similar answer I have already posted on this same subject.

Comment: The above comments are about MQ detecting a network issue after a connection is established.  There is also a setting that can be put into a mqclient.ini that Java and JMS APIs will look at for how long to way for an initial connection to fail.  With out this setting in place MQ defaults to the underlying OS defaults.  For Linux this is around 189 seconds, other OSs vary.

Comment: Thank you guys for this necessary information. The isue issue is resolved. The issue was related to memory. I was running 9 application simultaneously with setting 524 MB max memory. That why application was getting hanged.